# Using computer date and adding a day indicator

Tags: javascript, html, date, dayofmonth

I have been trying to display the following "on this **4<sup>th</sup>** day of **January** in the year **2022**"

using javascript on an HTML page

```js
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
const d = new Date();
var dayn = d.getDay()
var dayString;
if (dayn == 1) {
  dayString = "</b><sup>st</sup>"
} else if (dayn == 3) {
  dayString = "</b><sup>rd</sup>"
} else if (dayn >= 4) {
  dayString = "</b><sup>th</sup>"
} else {
  dayString = "</b><sup>nd</sup>"
}
var dateStr = "<b>" + dayn + dayString + "</b> day of<b> " + monthNames[d.getMonth()] + "</b> in the year <b>" + d.getFullYear(); + "</b>"
document.write(dateStr);
```

but for some reason it is displaying today as the 2nd and not the 4th ***and***

where I want to display ie. 4<sup>th</sup> March 2022 (today +89 days) it is failing to do so...

So the aim is to on the first line display:

"on this **4<sup>th</sup>** day of **January** in the year **2022**"

and on the next line

"no later than **3<sup>rd</sup>** day of **March 2022**"

Comment: `var dayn = d.getDay()` should be `var dayn = d.getDate()` Day refers to Day of Week. Since its Tuesday, it shows 2.

Comment: FANTASTIC Rajesh, Thanks!
If I want to do the second part, today +89 days? Can I create a second var?

Comment: Hi @Rajesh & Shibran
Thank you for assisting so far. Being a complete NOOB at this I have one more question being how do I use the JS in two places, with two different results on one HTML page as it does not seem to work where I tried it... :-(

So, firstly I want to display

"on this 4th day of January in the year 2022" - today's day/date 

and on the next line 

"no later than 3rd day of March 2022" - being 88 days after today's date

When I ran the two scripts on one page only the first one displayed which tells me the code can't be re-used?

Comment: @Staffie—if you have another question, post another question. Don't ask questions in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
const d = new Date();
var dayn = d.getDate();
var dayString;
if (dayn == 1) {
  dayString = "</b><sup>st</sup>"
} else if (dayn == 3) {
  dayString = "</b><sup>rd</sup>"
} else if (dayn >= 4) {
  dayString = "</b><sup>th</sup>"
} else {
  dayString = "</b><sup>nd</sup>"
}
var dateStr = "<b>" + dayn + dayString + "</b> day of<b> " + monthNames[d.getMonth()] + "</b> in the year <b>" + d.getFullYear(); + "</b>"
document.write(dateStr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `d.getDate()` instead of `d.getDay()`

```
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
  "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
const d = new Date();
var dayn = d.getDate();
var endDate = d.setDate(dayn + 89);
var daym = new Date(endDate).getDate();

var dayString;
if (dayn == 1) {
  dayString = "</b><sup>st</sup>"
} else if (dayn == 3) {
  dayString = "</b><sup>rd</sup>"
} else if (dayn >= 4) {
  dayString = "</b><sup>th</sup>"
} else {
  dayString = "</b><sup>nd</sup>"
}

var endDayString;
if (daym == 1) {
  endDayString = "</b><sup>st</sup>"
} else if (daym == 3) {
  endDayString = "</b><sup>rd</sup>"
} else if (daym >= 4) {
  endDayString = "</b><sup>th</sup>"
} else {
  endDayString = "</b><sup>nd</sup>"
}
 
var endDateStr = "<b>" + daym + endDayString + "</b> day of<b> " + monthNames[d.getMonth()] + "</b> in the year <b>" + d.getFullYear(); + "</b>"
document.write(endDateStr);
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! and to get today +89days?

Comment: @Staffie I have updated my answer for your 2nd question

Comment: Thanks Shibran but it seems I cant do both in one page ie
So the aim is to on the first line display:

"on this 4th day of January in the year 2022"

and on the next line

"no later than 3rd day of March 2022"

Comment: sorry I'm a COMPLETE NOOB when it comes to JS...